# Handling basic authentication result in web application - websphere

Tags: basic-authentication, websphere-7

I have a simple web application(eg:1.Add User 2.Delete User) deployed in Websphere 7.0 with sever level basic authetication enabled. I have created two roles and mapped to different credentials and my application works fine with security also. But my problem is 
User1 is having permission to access Add User page and User2 is having permission to access Delete User page . When User1 try to access delete user page my basic authentication denied that user and shows 403 forbidden error. But i want to handle this authetication result in my application and have to show customized Error page like "Sorry, authentication failed,You are allowed to access this page".

How to do this in my application. Is IBM providing any seperate api or any listener to doing this?

Note:my application using struts 2.0 + Spring 3.0 framework

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the error code on the web.xml file like explained on the link below.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448884

---

On my WebSphere Commerce project, the Struts-config file get that entry. Maybe it can help you.

```
<forward className="com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionForward"
            name="AccessControlErrorView" path="/GenericApplicationError.jsp">
            <set-property property="resourceClassName" value="com.ibm.commerce.command.HttpForwardViewCommandImpl"/>
            <set-property property="properties" value="storeDir=no"/>
</forward>
```